# rSyslog - Rule for all (UDP) remote massages

Tags: rsyslog, rules

Is there a way to create a rsyslog rule that will process all incoming udp traffic to a different file (the same way rules are written for subsystems)

So for example I would do something like this

```
udp.* /var/log/remoteSrv
```

The closest I have fund was how to change files based on the remote system but I'm just looking to know if the log came from the local machine or from a remote server.

http://www.rsyslog.com/storing-messages-from-a-remote-system-into-a-specific-file/

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can use the information in your link to derive something like the following, to put near the start of your config file:

```
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514
# do this in FRONT of the local/regular rules
if $fromhost-ip != '127.0.0.1' then /var/log/remoteSrv
& stop
# local/regular rules, like
*.* /var/log/syslog.log
```

This filters messages not from the localhost, `127.0.0.1`, to the wanted logfile, then suppresses them (`stop`). Then you can use whatever rules you already have for the remaining messages, for example as given in the last line.